# Unistall app from shell using ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb

I've connected the smarthpone (rooted) to the PC (Linux) with ADB. 
Eveything works fine excepts the fact that I can't unistall apps from shell. I've tried :

```
adb unistall com.mirsoft.passwordmemory
adb unistall -k com.mirsoft.passwordmemory
```

And I get the *help message* as return.
I've also tried:

```
adb shell pm unistall com.mirsoft.passwordmemory
adb shell pm unistall -k com.mirsoft.passwordmemory
```

Getting as return

```
Error: unknown command 'unistall'
```

followed by the *help message*.

Other commands works fine.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uninstall` has an `n` after the `i`. Use `adb uninstall com.mirsoft.passwordmemory`.

Comment: @Ollaw: That is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to uninstall with the rm command:

```
adb shell rm com.mirsoft.passwordmemory
```

*Don't​ forget typically the `su` command to grant the super user permissions.*